# Migrating an apps from iOS 6 to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I have an iOS 6 app that works fine and was accepted by iTunes when I upload it. Now I'm trying to update the apps so it will be compatible with iOS 7. It runs well both in the simulator and on an iPhone that ran from XCode 5. When I upload the app to iTunes, it succeeded. However, later the iTunes web site reported, "Invalid Binary". This is [one of my apps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kencan-jepang/id691018164?ls=1&mt=8).

I'm using sqlite database too.

I have tried many things from the forum due to my problem, but it's still "Invalid Binary". Would someone tell me what are the things that should be changed if we want to update our apps from iOS 6 to iOS 7?

Is it a problem with the code, or is the problem with my project setting such as Build Setting, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You likely just need to include a default image for supporting the iPhone 5.

It should be called:  Default-568h@2x.png
and should be 640 × 1136 pixels

Comment: I got an e-mail: Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.